# How to connect Node Sequelize to Amazon RDS MySQL with Multi-AZ probably

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, sequelize.js, amazon-rds

I'm using an Amazon RDS hosted MySQL with Multi-AZ Support. Just could not find any information on how to connect Sequelize to Amazon RDS properly so that Sequelize is handling fail-overs etc. accordingly?

I'm just using the following config, but do not know if this is enough or recommended?

```
sequelizeConfig = {
  logging: false,
  pool: { maxConnections: 5, maxIdleTime: 30},
  sequelizeConfig[dialectOptions] = {
    ssl: 'Amazon RDS'
  }
}
```

Using Amazon RDS with Multi-AZ I consider the following is important:

1. Try reconnecting if connection got lost, until it is available again
2. Don't cache mysql server ip address too long (Amazon suggests less than 1 min)

[Amazon Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.rds.html#create_deploy_nodejs.rds.newDB) are not writing anything about connection handling and pooling.

Comment: Did you get Node Sequelize.js to work with Amazon RDS MySQL?

Comment: Yes, but just sequelize, not sequelize-cli with migrations. Just use the regular SQL settings via environment variables plus the above settings as described in the aws docs

Comment: I see. Bummer. We started a EC2 instance and connect RDS via Security Group.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is how i got connected with my RDS:

```
 var config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
 // your config file will be in your directory
 var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, {
    host: '****.****.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
    port: 5432,
    logging: console.log,
    maxConcurrentQueries: 100,
    dialect: 'postgres',
    dialectOptions: {
        ssl:'Amazon RDS'
    },
    pool: { maxConnections: 5, maxIdleTime: 30},
    language: 'en'
})
```

Comment: can you provide an additional example for iam authentication please?

Comment: Thx for the fast reply anyways!

Comment: What do you put in the ssl? Just the string Amazon RDS??

Comment: Yes, I believe. I did it a year ago.

Comment: Worked for me, Except I used `dialect: 'mysql'` instead of postgres

Comment: @Manuel You have to create an auth token which you pass as password: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/RDS/Signer.html

Comment: I'm using sequelize 6.33.0 and node 18.17.1 and setting dialectOptions.ssl to 'Amazon RDS' results in an error. So this no longer works.

Comment: Can confirm @Mike Lane is right. It’s an error using ‘Amazon RDS’ now.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer didn't work for me, after some research, this options object did:

```
var options = {
  host: settings.database.host,
  port: settings.database.port,
  logging: console.log,
  maxConcurrentQueries: 100,
  dialect: 'mysql',
  ssl: 'Amazon RDS',
  pool: { maxConnections: 5, maxIdleTime: 30 },
  language: 'en',
}
```

I'm running a RDS MySQL and a EC2 instance in the same default VPC, this options object worked when connecting a node app from that EC2 with the RDS using sequelize.

Comment: FYI `maxConcurrentQueries` has not been used since 2014: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2405

Answer (score 0):

`ssl: 'Amazon RDS'` didn't work for me.

After some digging, this worked:

```
var options = {
  host: settings.database.host,
  port: settings.database.port,
  logging: console.log,
  dialect: 'mysql',
  "dialectOptions": {
        "ssl": {
            "ca": fs.readFileSync('./eu-central-1-bundle.pem')
        }
    }
}
```

Where eu-central-1-bundle.pem is aws CA certificate necessary to connect to the mysql rds DB.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "Some digging" where? [edit] your question to include supporting details.